How different quantum computing in four dimensions would be?
Would mathematic of quantum computing stay mostly similar, if one would be able to perform quantum computing in four dimensions using spin operators $S_{x}$, $S_{y}$, $S_{z}$ and $S_{w}$?

Are you talking about dimensions of space, or dimensions of local Hilbert spaces? It is not clear from the question. Also, the ST decomposition is not bounded to any particular dimensionality.

Good comment. What was in my mind was fourth physical dimension, that would be build of course artificially. But then I don't know enough about this to say, if it does or does not make sense, or if that type of structure can be build with spin-3/2:s or something similar.

Look up the spin group. We would build a quantum computer using the minimal irreducible representation of Spin(4), which is a double covering of SO(4). Also, since angular momentum is a hodge dual, it would be a two-form and have six generators in four spatial dimensions! I feel like your question is rather about the nature of the angular momentum algebra in four spatial dimensions than specifically quantum computing.

The question can be interpreted in a number of ways, but I’ll assume with your reference to Trotter-Suzuki that you mean if we can gain anything by laying out qubits in four dimensions, as opposed to, say, a two-dimensional grid as is common in many current superconducting designs, or even a three-dimensional stack of qubits such as some designs being pursued by IBM and others.
In short and under that interpretation, nothing interesting comes to mind.
For example, take two-local simulation, where each term of a Hamiltonian only acts on two qubits at a time. But any 2-local Hamiltonian corresponds to a graph of qubits with vertices corresponding to the two qudits upon which the Hamiltonian acts and edges corresponding to the local terms.
Importantly any graph can be embedded into 3-space. Adding a fourth dimension of (geometric) locality doesn’t add anything not already achievable with three dimensions.  Trotterization wouldn’t care if the qubits were in 3-space or not.
Indeed even qubits laid out in a single line in one dimension with only nearest neighbor interactions could, with polynomial overhead, simulate any local Hamiltonian regardless of the underlying dimensionality, just by SWAP'ping qubits around. There's a reason we refer to a Turing tape, and not a Turing sheet or cube or tesseract.

There is a big difference if we have spin operators $S_{x}$ and $S_{y}$, or $S_{x}$, $S_{y}$ and $S_{z}$. Question is what would change if possible spin operators would be $S_{1}$, $S_{2}$, $S_{3}$ and $S_{4}$,

Your comment seems more directed at physics in four dimensions, like the Spin(4) group. If you want to simulate four-dimensional spin in four spatial dimensions, you would probably build a quantum computer consisting of qubits that are representations of Spin(4) rather than Spin(3). If you only have three spatial dimensions like most of us do, you would need to think about an encoding into Spin(3) qubits and then @Mark Spinelli's answer applies again (assuming you are using a 2-local encoding).

"If you only have three spatial dimension" : There is a possibility at least in theory to produce such hardware where fourth dimension is produced artificially into system. Since I am theoretical physics it is not my problem to do actual work with hardware. My job would be to complain that totally unfair since tehcnology is not advanced enough to test such hypothesis as string theories etc. ;)

We’d have a better shot at building a self-correcting memory.
